# Best practice for uploading and binding a model that has a file in ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I am developing a backend service for my Android application. The backend is developed in **ASP.NET Web Api**.

Now I have encountered a problem with **binding my model**. I have a `User` model which has typical fields such as `Name`, `Age` and etc. And currently I am sending the data from the application in the form of **JSON** to the service, which is bound perfectly to my `User` model.

However now I need to add **another field** in my `User` class, which is a **profile image**. I know that I can send image files via JSON if I convert them to byte arrays, but is that a good approach?

Another way I could think of is to send the model and the image file **separately**. Then just associate the image's `GUID` to the `User` model's profile image field. But this also doesn't make sense because the image file upload is obviously **slower** than `User` json file, so by the time I receive the `User` json and initialise a new `User` , the file might still be uploading and hence **no chance** of getting the `GUID` from it.

Can anyone suggest a good design for this? I believe this is a very common functionality of any service that involves user account management. How is it normally done?

Comment: I think sending byte[] is the better approach.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment. Why would you reccommend so? wouldn't converting to byte array increase the size?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

HTML

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="OK" />
    }
```

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // This action renders the form
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // This action handles the form POST and the upload
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        // Verify that the user selected a file
        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0) 
        {
            // extract only the filename
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
        // redirect back to the index action to show the form once again
        return RedirectToAction("Index");        
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm afraid this does not answer my question. I am looking for a way to bind the image along with my user model, the design.